# How do I change the priority of a process via Ruby

Tags: ruby

When I exec a Ruby process, how can I have that process lower it's priority? I've looked at the documentation for Process.setpriority but I just don't get it. Does anyone have an example of how a Ruby process would lower it's own priority?

Chris

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second argument in setpriority (and getpriority) indicates the process you want to change; using 0 will specify the current process.

If you look at the [ruby source for Process.setpriority](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/process_8c-source.html) all this call is doing is calling the underlying OS setpriority call. On unix the priority can be between -20 and 20 where -20 is the most favorable and 20 is the least favorable for scheduling. So if you want to boost the current process as high as it can go you would do:

```
Process.setpriority(Process::PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20)
```

Comment: I'll check this out but points for explaining that the 0 refers to the current process. - Chris